# dynamic filling of a slider revolution post-based slider layer

Tags: wordpress, slider, slider-revolution

In slider revolution (wordpress plugin) in a post-based slider I need to change the content of a layer (<rs-layer...>) AND its layer-wrapper (<rs-layer-wrap...>) depending on the category of the respective post.

I guess it is in \wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\output.class.php.

But I cannot locate the place of the code, where rs-layer-wrap and rs-layer are filled ...

Thx in advance and best regards
Markus